# Reference in an article

Tags: meaning-in-context

I may come off as silly but somehow i am not able to make out the meaning of this sentence from a big article "by short-circuiting the internal critiques of society,the liberal left has played into the xenophobia of trump"
Can anyone interpret this?
I am also attaching the link 
http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/Questioning-the-liberal-Left/article14636562.ece
Thabk you!

Comment: Which part poses the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

There is a saying, "Those who make peaceful change impossible make violent change inevitable."

This is somewhat similar.  In the US, working-class whites who have struggled both economically and socially in the last few decades not only have been ignored by the elites, those who have tried to verbalized their concerns have been stigmatized as reactionaries, as "bitter clingers", as racists.

What the author is saying is that the "short-circuiting" -- that is, by preventing discussion of the concerns of this population even being aired -- the "liberal left" (that is, the generally, but not radically, progressive Democrats) created a space for someone like Trump, who was willing to trample over ideas about civility and decency.  After all, to the people that voted for him, the Democrats used civility and decency as a club against people like them.

(This is my interpretation of what the article is saying; I don't necessarily agree with it.)